# Eclipse Photon Lag When Typing in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, lag

I work on Spring MVC project in Eclipse Photon, The problem is that When I type in java pages the IDE becomes unresponsive, It takes 2 or 3 sec to type a character and same behavior when backspacing too. I have tried some suggestions from other posts
**System config** :{ i5 8th gen, 8gb ram, 5400rpm hdd, win10 x64 }
**plugins installed**:{jboss tools}
**Things I already tried** :{ reinstalled eclipse photon,disabled validators, added -Xverify:none to eclipse.ini file, disabled everything in Content Assist}
This lags only occur when editing the file, navigation and opening pages are fine.

Comment: Is this happening for all .java files?  Are some worse than others?  How large are the source files?

Comment: Where are the files you're editing located? Locally?

Comment: @IanMcLaird Yes, its happening across all .java files, I work with java files which has 300+, 500+ ,and some are 1000+ lines...but the issue is same for all files even for files with 60 lines.

Comment: @nitind eclipse is located at default location ie, in C drive, my workspace is in drive W:/workspace/

Comment: The drive W: is where?

Comment: Just another partition @nitind

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that the eclipse workspace, installation and the project was at different directories [different logical drives].
Also It was running on hard disk.
After bringing all thos location to one single logical drive did the trick for me, also i added a ssd which made everything smooth now